# how can modify the package name in admob?

Tags: google-play, admob

Maybe this place is Unallocated to the non-technical subject but I hope help me solve my problem

My developer account has been deleted on Google Play ..

I want to re-Publish my applications at the new developer account in the new Google Play

The problem is: I want to modify the publisher ID in Admob

Can I add new applications to Admob and ignore the legacy applications deleted?

Or is there a way I can modify the package name of the old application to be linked to new apps url instead of linking the old apps url ?

Thank you very much to all help me

Answer (score 1):

> Can I add new applications to Admob and ignore the legacy applications deleted?

Yes you can.